# Есть ли в css такие иконки или как добавить в input картинки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, input

Есть ли в css   иконки как на картинке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я нашел только такие `&#9729 и &#36;` еще есть вариант вставить картинкой в input  есть ли способ это сделать?

Comment: Фонт авесом, ион икон, материал и т д

Comment: Не очень понял, можно чуть подробнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Качаете [этот шрифт](https://fontawesome.ru/all-icons/), копируете с этой же страницы нужную иконку (там их тьма) и вставляете куда нужно! Чтобы установить шрифт, нужно написать в CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: НазваниеШрифта;
    src: url('ПутьКШрифту/НазваниеШрифта');
}
```

*P.S.: Название шрифта пишется с расширением (прим. MyFont.ttf или MyFont.otf)*

*P.P.S.: ПутьКШрифту - это папка на вашем сайте, куда вы положили файл скачанного шрифта*

Comment: Удалось установить по инструкции вот этой https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5Ub-MXKMgA иконки работают но в инпут их не вставишь(

Comment: все дело в том, что они вставляются в таком формате <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> то биш в инпут не добавить

Comment: Попробовал вставить с помощью позиционирования смотрится не очень, т.к. под позишн абсолют не выделяется место, возможно есть еще какой нибудь способ?

Comment: смотрите в направлении псевдоэлементов :before и :after (CSS). если помог ответом - можете выбрать его как лучший ответ :)